# How often should you update angular/node packages

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

My problem with node/angular versions is:

- Say we are 10 developers working on a project, it is hard to control
  everyone's `node_modules` to get it working everywhere
- I also have issues when opening older projects, many times packages have updated so much that I battle to just get `ng serve` to work after `npm install`

So I basically have two options:

- Update the project and all it's modules very regularly, which can become a hassle I think
- Lock the versions, but then you are "stuck" with bugs and problems that newer versions could fix

What are most other people's solutions to node/angular updating things so regularly? Every month or two `ng install` on the same project throws many breaking issues.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

Comment: *which can become a hassle* - I'd prefer a routine over the hours of troubleshooting any day. *but then you are "stuck" with bugs and problems that newer versions could fix* - newer version is not necessarily better. This should be treated on per package basis, change log is your best friend. It's hardly a good idea to use loose version constraints, to the point when reinstalling packages can introduce breaking changes. `~` constraint for trusted packages and strict version constraint for the rest is what I'd do as a rule of thumb. Package lock is additional measure. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Personally, I saw a lot strict versions. Usually, the upgrades are made one package at a time, and only when a new development need arises that could be facilitated by upgrading one or some of the dependencies. However, the lower the layer, the trickier the migration, for instance when you have to up Node itself. But the time taken then is actually what you saved by not having troubles with versions upgrading as they are published, without notice and with you ending up wondering what happened for the build to crash now. Preferably on a friday afternoon, of course. In short: I agree with @estus